# What is the role of the "interface {}" syntax in Go?

Tags: interface, go

I've read through the Effective Go and Go Tutorials as well as some source, but the exact mechanism behind the `interface {}` syntax is Go is somewhat mysterious to me. I first saw it when trying to implement `heap.Interface` and it seems to be a container of some kind (reminds me of a monad a little) from which I can extract values of arbitrary type.

Why is Go written to use this?  Is it some kind of workaround for generics? Is there a more elegant way to get values from a `heap.Interface` than having to dereference them with `heap.Pop(&h).(*Foo)` (in the case of a heap pointers to type Foo)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`interface{}` is a generic box that can hold everything. Interfaces in go define a set of methods, and any type which implements these methods conforms to the interface. `interface{}` defines no methods, and so by definition, every single type conforms to this interface and therefore can be held in a value of type `interface{}`.

It's not really like generics at all. Instead, it's a way to relax the type system and say "any value at all can be passed here". The equivalent in C for this functionality is a `void *` pointer, except in Go you can query the type of the value that's being held.

Comment: Ahh, it's an anonymous type! Got it, thank you!  I guess I'd use some kind of reflection to query the type held.  I haven't worked with that part yet; so far I've just used the (odd, to me) `.(<some type>)` syntax to get back values.

Comment: There's a reflect package that can let you query the type, or you can use a type switch, which looks similar to a regular switch but the cases are types. Or you can just use the non-erroring version of a type assertion (e.g. `value, ok := foo.(type)`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent [blog post](http://research.swtch.com/2009/12/go-data-structures-interfaces.html) that explains what is going on under the hood.